# space between volume and number with Biblatex (authoryear) does not work

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to get rid of the space between volume and number, and it actually worked with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[backend = biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=authoryear-comp, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
 \printfield{volume}
 \printfield{number}
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}
 \printfield{eid}}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
 \printbibliography

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
    @Article{Ratcliff,
       author  = {R. Ratcliff and G. McKoon},
       title   = {The diffusion decision model: Theory and data for two-choice decision tasks},
       journal = {Neural Computing and Applications},
       year    = {2008},
       volume  = {20},
       number  = {4},
       pages   = {873-922},
       }

\end{filecontents}
```

I don't know what happened, but it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\printfield{volume}%`, i.e. adding a `%`.

Comment: You should also add a `%` after `\printfield{number}` and `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you want to write an answer, or is this a duplicate of [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864)

Comment: My actual problem was also that it used to work without `%` and I don't know what has changed. I also had to add `%` to `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{`

Comment: In certain situations it can work without `%` because `biblatex` is really good at cleaning up punctuation mess. But there comes a point where `biblatex` can't do anything any more. Indeed you also should have a `%` in the very first line. Cf. my comments in http://golatex.de/spacing-zwischen-volume-und-number-t19054.html